# Ruby(Hard Way) Ex48 - Why won't this Integer(param).to_s => "string"?

Tags: ruby

I've tried using `Integer(word)` which in `irb` `=> 1234` understandably, but when iI program `num = word.to_s` or `Integer(word).to_s` it still outputs an Integer.

I see the difference in the test, but the input doesn't matter right?

All ints should output as strings?

1. Why is this?
2. How can I fix it?

For context, I'm attempting to complete this exercise...

http://ruby.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex48.html

#### My code

```
class Lexicon

Pair = Struct.new(:token, :key)

def scan(stuff)
    @words = stuff.split(" ")
    return analyze
end


def analyze

    hash = { "north" => :direction, "south" => :direction, "east" => :direction, "west" => :direction, 
            "go" => :verb, "stop" => :verb, "kill" => :verb, "eat" => :verb, 
            "the" => :stop, "in" => :stop, "of" => :stop, "from" => :stop, "at" => :stop, "it" => :stop, 
            "door" => :noun, "bear" => :noun, "princess" => :noun, "cabinet" => :noun}

    @words.map do |word|
        #hash.keys.include?(word) ? Pair.new(hash[word], word) : Pair.new(:error, word)
            begin
                Integer(word).to_s
                                    #Integer(word)
                                    #num = word.to_s
                                    #Pair.new(:number, num)
                Pair.new(:number, word)
            rescue ArgumentError => x
                if hash.keys.include?(word)
                    Pair.new(hash[word], word)
                else
                    Pair.new(:error, word)
                end
            end

       end
  end
end
```

#### Terminal

```
$ ruby test_lexicon.rb
Run options: 

# Running tests:

[4/6] LexiconTests#test_numbers = 0.00 s           
  1) Failure:
test_numbers(LexiconTests) [test_lexicon.rb:49]:
<[#<struct Lexicon::Pair token=:number, key="1234">]> expected but was
<[#<struct Lexicon::Pair token=:number, key=1234>]>.

Finished tests in 0.004981s, 1204.5774 tests/s, 2208.3919 assertions/s.
6 tests, 11 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

ruby -v: ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]
```

#### Exercise snippet (test file)

```
def test_numbers()
        assert_equal(@@lexicon.scan("1234"), [Pair.new(:number, 1234)])
        result = @@lexicon.scan("3 91234")
        assert_equal(result, [Pair.new(:number, 3),
                Pair.new(:number, 91234)])
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this block:

```
            Integer(word).to_s
            Pair.new(:number, num)
```

You reference a variable `num`, which isn't declared in the code you've pasted. It seems that you're not testing what you think you're testing.

However, the failure:

```
<[#<struct Lexicon::Pair token=:number, key="1234">]> expected but was
<[#<struct Lexicon::Pair token=:number, key=1234>]>.
```

...is misleading. [The test](http://ruby.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex48.html#exercise-48-advanced-user-input#what-you-should-test):

```
assert_equal(@@lexicon.scan("1234"), [Pair.new(:number, 1234)])
```

...is looking for the result of `@@lexicon.scan("1234")` to be `[Pair.new(:number, 1234)]`. That is the `expected` and `actual` arguments to [`assert_equal`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Test/Unit/Assertions/assert_equal) are transposed.

So you are returning the `String("1234")` when actually the `Integer(1234)` is what is required.

In short, therefore, your block needs to be:

```
    Pair.new(:number, Integer(word))
```

...and your tests should all pass.

Comment: @JayBobo: It wasn't *your* code that was misleading, the code in http://ruby.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex48.html#what-you-should-test has the arguments backwards.

Comment: I understand, I feel better knowing I had the right idea somewhat lol. I meant not including the param word in the new instance of Pair. Thanks again.